# How to load header and footer .html dynamicaly

Tags: php, header, include, footer

I am trying to include a header and footer dynamically with an url like this:

```
<?php include("http://www.monsite.com/layout/header.html"); ?>
```

but it doesn't work.

Anybody can help me ?

Thanks you.

Comment: Are you sure you are wanting to include the HTML content from a different URL? (Use file_get_contents for that) Or do you just need include("header.html");

Comment: I need to load the header in my page. And I have just the url, I haven't the path.

Comment: <?php echo file_get_contents("http://www.monsite.com/layout/header.html"); ?>

Comment: Mex  it's almost that..

Answer (score 3):

[`include()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php) expects a physical path on the file server, not a URL.

> Files are included based on the file path given or, if none is given, the include_path specified. If the file isn't found in the include_path, include will finally check in the calling script's own directory and the current working directory before failing.

```
<?php include("/root/path/to/layout/header.html"); ?>
```

Comment: I haven't the path to include this header. The header are based on an another website. I have juste the url.

Comment: Then you can't use them until you copy the HTML or PHP to your server

Comment: I think include it's not the solution I have use that but I don't know how to do that.

Comment: I have an url an that's all and i need to load this header in my page

Comment: You should check your php.ini (`phpinfo()`) if `allow_url_fopen` and/or `allow_url_include` is 0 you won't be able to load content from external URLs - unless you have cURL

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the path you added in include function is correct.I think you are doing mistake in path of header file.

```
<?php include("root/path/layout/header.html"); ?>
```