# PHP to build HTML

Tags: php, html

Currently I am building a website in which I am trying to have one location (e.g. header.html or header.txt) to edit content on multiple pages (e.g. each page has the header). I assumed I could easily do this using PHP, importing the html code into the pages using

```
<?php 
echo file_get_contents("header.txt");
// or echo file_get_html("header.html");
?>
```

Does not seem to be working. Any suggestions on how to do this? I want to be able to edit the header across all pages from one location.

Take care!

EDIT: Okay so I think I am making a simple mistake that prevents the php to run. Just to lay out what I have and what I want to do:

1: I have a piece of code that represents the header that I want to include on multiple pages. This is currently saved in a header.html file.
2: I have a webpage saved as trial.html where I am trying to place that piece of code using php.

Am I forgetting something?

Comment: If the other file is written in php, you can use the include function, and it might not need to be php.

Comment: The include (or require) statement takes all the text/code/markup that exists in the specified file and copies it into the file that uses the include statement.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP - Load header from another file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34490165/php-load-header-from-another-file) or [How to load header and footer html dynamically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28551552/how-to-load-header-and-footer-html-dynamicaly)

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem. That code runs fine when I test it.

Comment: is your path to header.html correct? are you fetcing the file?

Comment: Hey! Thanks for the load of answers. Really appreciate it. I think I might be making some rooky mistakes. I literally learned PHP yesterday. I am probably doing something wrong. Here is what I am doing:
I have a .html file that presents a page; I have a header.txt, header.html, and header.php file with the exact code I need (didn't know which type I needed); I want the code of the header. file to be placed in a specific location in the .html file. I am trying to pull it in using php referencing it from an URL.
Am I taking the right approach? Should I have a .php file instead of .html?

Answer (score 1):

You are making it too complicated:

```
<?php 
 require_once('header.php');
```

It does not matter if header.php contains just html, just php, or some mix of both.

Answer (score 0):

Use `PHP` files, no plain `html` or `txt` because `PHP` can be protected to prevent directly access, include more parameters and your project can be more modular.

When you [include](http://php.net/manual/es/function.include.php)(or [require](http://php.net/manual/es/function.require.php)) php files, those are included in the main file before page loads (server side), so you can have more variables in it.

#### header.php

```
<?php
echo '<title>Welcome</title>';
```

#### body.php

```
<?php
echo '<h1>Hellow world!</h1>';
$custom_page = 'page 01';
```

#### footer.php

```
<?php
echo '<p>My site footer for ' . $custom_page . '</p>';
```

#### index.php

```
<?php
// debug errors
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);

// Note: __DIR__ is absolute path for current file (index.php)
// if you have to go up one dir:
// include_once __DIR__ . '/../your_file.php';
// if you have to go down one dir:
// include_once __DIR__ . '/subdir/your_file.php';

/* more code */
?>
<html>
    <header>
        <?php include_once __DIR__ . '/header.php'; ?>
    </header>
    <body>
        <?php include_once __DIR__ . '/body.php'; ?>
        <?php include_once __DIR__ . '/footer.php'; ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

#### Rendered HTML for index.php

```
<html>
    <header>
        <title>Welcome</title>
    </header>
    <body>
        <h1>Hellow world!</h1>
        <p>My site footer for page 01</p>
    </body>
</html>
```

Recommended reading <sup>*first page on google result*</sup>:

- [PHP Getting Started](http://php.net/manual/en/getting-started.php)
- [How To Start Programming](http://howtostartprogramming.com/PHP/)
- [Getting Started With PHP: Basic Scripts](https://www.cloudways.com/blog/how-to-start-php-programming/)

Comment: I have tried all your suggestions but somehow what only shows up now is a dot (very similar to a list-decoration dot); Besides that it is blank. Any idea?

Comment: All files are in the same `path`? (also add `error_reporting` to index.php to debug errors, see edit)

Comment: They are hosted on the same webpage (same root) but they are in different folders (e.g. page is /dev/trial.php and the header.php is /htmlblocks/header.php) Could that be the problem?

Comment: Sure, you have to set up the right path on each `include` line

Comment: But they do not necessarily need to be in the same folder right? php code 
`<?php 
echo "Php is running.";
include('htmlblocks/header.php'); 
?>`

Comment: absolutely not... but you *must* specify the right location of the included file.

Comment: Okay great. And yes, I do believe I did this. The header.php page itself shows exactly what I need imported. It just does not show up in the trial.php page. Would you mind having a look at the webpage with me? Maybe I am missing something? http://courseroot.com/courses/development/trial.php and http://courseroot.com/htmlblocks/header.php

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/151348/discussion-between-valentijn-van-den-hout-and-gmo).

Answer (score 0):

Problem ended up being in the path towards the file I wanted to include, as well as a multitude of other issues:

1. `header.html` -> `header.php`
2. `index.html` (page) -> `index.php`
3. `get_contents` -> `include`
4. `include('/path/file')` -> `include 'path/file'`
5. add `set_include_path($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']);`

Thanks everybody for you input!